# What is minimum requirement for adding an event to Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a simple event and enter it into a public Google Calendar on top of shared hosting plan using this code

```
<?php
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Halloween');
$event->setLocation('The Neighbourhood');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2019-09-31T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2019-09-31T10:25:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('ID@group.calendar.google.com', $event); //Returns array not an object

echo $createdEvent->id;
```

Apparently I can not use the `composer` easily on Godaddy so code is complaining as:

> This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package

But the full package is too large! What files do I really need in case of adding the event to calendar?

Comment: GoDaddy supported SOPA/SIPA bill that would allow crony competitors to post literally *any* copyrighted material on your website, run straight to the FBI and have your site taken down and domain name stolen without *any due process*. I highly recommend doing business with a company that isn't hostile towards your goals.

Comment: Also I was able to create events via XSS AJAX instead of server-to-server; I can't help with creating an object in PHP to send.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a proper IDE supporting XDebug you can set a breakpoint in your script, executing it step by step and have a look which classes will be included.

Optionally you can have a look into the XDebug documentation if there is an option to log the whole stack trace of a script execution and therefore get the classes loaded during execution.

**Edit:**

A third, and in the first place the easiest, approach is to manipulate `Google/autoload.php` to log all classes, interfaces, etc. loaded.

Comment: If one is downvoting that one must know better and should post that better approach. Unless the one doesn't, a downvote isn't much helpful.